# How to set up Skype on a HiDPI system?

Tags: resolution, skype

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Retina MacBook Pro. Everything works great, and the HiDPI is great in most apps.

However, Skype is one app that doesn't scale properly. Is there any way to fix this and get Skype to display at the same scale that everything else does?

Answer (score 2):

> Skype is a Qt program, and needs to be configured separately. You cannot change the DPI setting for it, but at least you can change font size. Install qt4 and run qtconfig-qt4 to do it.

Source: [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Skype)